# Unicode woes on a MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard, unicode

While using a MacBook Pro, I set the keyboard to US and Unicode.
When I try inputting a Unicode set holding down <kbd>Opt</kbd>, I only get 4 separate characters. For example, if I enter 2621 holding down the option I get... `™§™¡`

What am I doing wrong? Sticky keys are off and I get the same results on an external keyboard.

Comment: Have you switched the input source to Unicode via the Input Menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't actually using the Unicode Hex keyboard.  You have to see this (U+) in the top right corner of your screen for it to be active.  Then holding down option and typing 2621 produces ☡

[image]